# How to add class in plugin only for network site?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions, multisite

I created an input field in general - settings. It's in a plugin for a for a local ngo network site.

It looks like this, and it works great.

```
$ngob_sitelist_slug = new ngob_sitelist_slug();

class ngob_sitelist_slug {
    function ngob_sitelist_slug( ) {
        add_filter( 'admin_init' , array( &$this , 'ngob_register_slug' ) );
    }
    function ngob_register_slug() {
        register_setting( 'general', 'sitelist_slug', 'esc_attr' );
        add_settings_field('sitelist_slug', '<label for="sitelist_slug">'.__('Slug för site-lista' , 'ngo-branding' ).'</label>' , array(&$this, 'ngob_slug_html') , 'general' );
    }
    function ngob_slug_html() {
        $value = get_option( 'sitelist_slug', '' );
        echo '<input type="text" id="sitelist_slug" name="sitelist_slug" value="' . $value . '" />';
    }
}
```

However I only want it to be created for the network (main) site on a WPMU installation.

So I did this;

```
    // Get site id
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

// Check if we are on network site
if( is_main_site( $blog_id ) ) {

    $ngob_sitelist_slug = new ngob_sitelist_slug();

    class ngob_sitelist_slug {
        function ngob_sitelist_slug( ) {
            add_filter( 'admin_init' , array( &$this , 'ngob_register_slug' ) );
        }
        function ngob_register_slug() {
            register_setting( 'general', 'sitelist_slug', 'esc_attr' );
            add_settings_field('sitelist_slug', '<label for="sitelist_slug">'.__('Slug för site-lista' , 'ngo-branding' ).'</label>' , array(&$this, 'ngob_slug_html') , 'general' );
        }
        function ngob_slug_html() {
            $value = get_option( 'sitelist_slug', '' );
            echo '<input type="text" id="sitelist_slug" name="sitelist_slug" value="' . $value . '" />';
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get this error when reloading the page:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ngob_sitelist_slug' not found...(shortened the output, since it's mostly path:s)
```

Why is that? Im fairly novis on classes to start with, but when *not* on network site, the class doesn't get executed, so no problem, as expected.
But when *on* network site, I get above error..

How to mend this so I can get that input field, but only on the main (network) site?

I don't fully understand what the problem is, and it seems hard to find anything on google about this. I guess you can't wrap a class in an if? But why not, and mostly, how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

How are you invoking `ngob_sitelist_slug`?

I'm gonna guess that you are doing something like `$my_class = new ngob_sitelist_slug;`. Doing it this way would require that your class have a [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). if it doesn't, you'll get an error.

You could still call your class methods statically:

```
$my_thing = ngob_sitelist_slug::my_method();
```

Though technically you should add the `static` keyword to your methods in this case.

Also I see that in your case you are using $this, so you really need a constructor.

EDIT:
I now realize you do have a constructor - albeit a deprecated one.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I have more to learn about classes. Read a bit in php docs, and mostly used examples I could find. You know of somewhere to read it more condensed with examples?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing this;

```
class ngob_sitelist_slug {
    function ngob_sitelist_slug( ) {
        // Check if we are on network site
        if( is_main_site( $blog_id ) ) {
            add_filter( 'admin_init' , array( &$this , 'ngob_register_slug' ) );
        }
    }
```

The rest of the code is the same. But I guess there has to be a better aproach? How *should* you do it?